# mongodb - How to invert query with $not?

Tags: mongodb

I want to select all documents except those with code starting with AAA if the name is also equals to BB or CC.

I think the last query below is explicit, I would of course expect to get 225506-125102 documents, and not 0. So the result here is definitely unexpected.

```
> db.amon.find().count()
225506
> db.amon.find({code: /^AAA/, 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}).count()
125102
> db.amon.find({$not: {code: /^AAA/, 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}}).count()
0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is the query you're running that's not giving the right results? What version of MongoDB are you using? Your [`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) query is not a valid query in MongoDB 2.6:

```
> db.amon.find({ "$not" : { "code" : /^AAA/, "name" : { "$in" : ["BB", "CC"] } } })
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $not",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Here's an example that does what you want:

```
> db.amon.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66bdf9b63e0dd3ca1a18"),
    "code" : "AAA",
    "name" : "AA"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66c1f9b63e0dd3ca1a19"),
    "code" : "AAA",
    "name" : "BB"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66c3f9b63e0dd3ca1a1a"),
    "code" : "AAA",
    "name" : "CC"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66d3f9b63e0dd3ca1a1b"),
    "code" : "BBB",
    "name" : "AA"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66d6f9b63e0dd3ca1a1c"),
    "code" : "BBB",
    "name" : "BB"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66daf9b63e0dd3ca1a1d"),
    "code" : "BBB",
    "name" : "CC"
}
> db.amon.find({ 
    "$or" : [
        { "code" : { "$not" : /^AAA/ } }, 
        { "name": { "$not" : { "$in" : ["BB", "CC"] } } } 
    ] 
})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66bdf9b63e0dd3ca1a18"), "code" : "AAA", "name" : "AA" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66d3f9b63e0dd3ca1a1b"), "code" : "BBB", "name" : "AA" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66d6f9b63e0dd3ca1a1c"), "code" : "BBB", "name" : "BB" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ea66daf9b63e0dd3ca1a1d"), "code" : "BBB", "name" : "CC" }
```

The easy way to write down this query is to use [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws): the complement of an intersection (and) is the union of the complements. Since you are searching for documents that don't satisfy (code is AAA) and (name is one of BB or CC), the condition they satisfy is not ((code is AAA) and (name is one of BB or CC)) = (code is not AAA) or (name is not BB or CC).

Comment: Yes ! That makes it. Thanks. And also thanks for the reference to DeMorgan's Laws so I can put a name on this common rule. Thats a perfectly valid and detailed answer.

Comment: A small improvement to the answer would be to use the $nin operator instead of $not, then $in.

Answer (score 12):

### The problem

[`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) can't be used to simply invert an existing expression.

```
var originalSelection = {code: /^AAA/, 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}
var invalidSelection = {$not:originalSelection}
```

> "unknown top level operator: $not"

---

### The solution

The simple solution is to use the [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator, passing the expression as a single-item array.

```
var inverseSelection = {$nor:[originalSelection]}
```

*This works because NOR of a single operand is equivalent to NOT.*

Comment: This made me realize that the word "nor" in neither-nor in English is basically a negation of "or" (head-explode-emoji)

Answer (score 2):

Use $ne or $nin   See link [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/)

```
db.amon.find().count() 225506
db.amon.find({code: /^AAA/, 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}).count() 125102
db.amon.find({$not: {code: /^AAA/, 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}}).count() 0

could be 

db.amon.find({code: { $ne : /^AAA/}, 'author.name': {'$nin': ['BB', 'CC']}}}).count() 

and if you want this to work as index only then create a compond index on the 2 fields

db.amon.find({code: { $ne : /^AAA/}, 'author.name': {'$nin': ['BB', 'CC']}}},{code:1,_id:0}).count()

and if you want it to work on a sharded cluster
db.amon.find({code: { $ne : /^AAA/}, 'author.name': {'$nin': ['BB', 'CC']}}},{code:1,_id:0}).explain().n
```

Comment: Can you re-write the OP's query using the correct operator as an example?

Comment: Hi, that's not good, as you also have only one part of the results. You're missing the documents where {code: /^AAA/} and 'author.name' are not {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}, and you're also missing the documents where {code: { $ne : /^AAA/} and 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}

Comment: Specific note for $ne and $not. They seems to have the same effect. Not sure which one is the best. I would bet that as the regular expression returns a boolean, the $not is more appropriate, as we're not talking about any "equality".

Answer (score 0):

Just going by the problem statement, I think this query should work for you:

```
db.amon.find({$and:[{code: {$not:/^AAA/}},{ 'author.name': {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}]}).count();
```

Comment: Not working, because you're missing the records when {code: /^AAA/} and 'author.name' are not {'$in': ['BB', 'CC']}}